# how to read .csv Chinese file in java and Why these two lead to different result

Tags: java, eclipse

```
BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1.csv"));
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("1.csv"), "utf-8"));
```

What's different above two ?
Why reader2's result is "??????????"
but reader1 is ok

Comment: The default encoding is probably "utf-16" (not "utf-8").

Comment: ```FileStreamReader``` is used for reading raw stream of bytes of a file, generally images. ```FileReader``` is the class suited for reading characters from a file. If you could provide the complete code we can help you realise why the former does not work for you.

Comment: The first one uses the default charset for your system which may not be 'utf-8'. You need to know what charset the file is using.

Answer (score 2):

See [Javadoc of *FileReader*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileReader.html):

> The constructors of this class assume that the **default character
>   encoding** [...] are appropriate.

Or with other words, `1.csv` seems to be encoded with the system default encoding, not with UTF-8 and the following will not output `utf-8` or `UTF-8`:

```
System.out.println(new FileReader("1.csv").getEncoding());
```

See also: [`Charset.defaultCharset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset--)